# Scheduled tasks in heroku environment

Tags: node.js, heroku, scheduled-tasks

I'm coming from a windows/.net background and am fairly new to Heroku/Node.js. In windows, it was typical on a web or database server to be able to set up a scheduled job that would run some sort of custom exe you could build with the MS toolchain. In Node on Heroku, I've come across something similar in agenda:

https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda

What confuses me is - would I add agenda tasks as part of my node server? That seems fundamentally bad that I'm mixing the web server with starting my scheduled tasks. Would it be a new app that I spin up on heroku that connects to the same DB under the covers? What is the correct infrastructure for a "scheduled task" in this ecosystem?

Comment: Have you looked at [Heroku Scheduler](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler)? There are even other scheduler add-ons, but that is the "default" one.

Comment: Hi Two-Bit Alchemist, I have looked in to it, but scheduler came with a stern warning that it's not reliable. This is going to be a "must run every day" type of functionality, and heroku advises to roll your own in that case.

Comment: Can you link to where you read that? I believe the warning is that you need it to run _this exact second_ every day, use something else. It's a "best effort" scheduler. I personally use it for tasks that must run even every hour, and it's never let me down. It may vary when it runs by 1 or 2 minutes, but that's it.

Comment: Sure, I'm seeing it here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler "If scheduled jobs are a critical component of your application, it is recommended to run a custom clock process instead for more reliability, control, and visibility."

Comment: Which means: We only offer basic settings (every 15 min, every hour, every day, which is far less than a familiar cron-like scheduler would support), only basic logging, and no precise guarantees about runtimes (every hour might mean 1:01:27 apart on average). There are other solutions if that's not good enough.

Comment: Sounds like that what i should try then, I read it as "this may not run on some days and that's to be expected" Add it as an answer and maybe a link to a tutorial on it please? I'd like to give you credit.